# Easy way to check if all field are not fill by the user

Tags: php, validation

I have a form that consists of a few sections. But, the sections are optional. In each section there are many fields that need to be filled. Once user submits, it will create an object of from that section. In the other sections, except for the last section, I have simply put a button to skip the section. I'm having a problem with the last section. Is there an easy way to check if all of the fields in the form of last section have been filled?

Comment: Put your form code here. It will be easy to understand your problem

Comment: Are you wanting server side or client side validation? (You should always have server side, client side can be bypassed). You tagged the post as PHP which indicates server side...but describe a client side solution...

Comment: `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { /* your check.... */}`

Comment: As you said that you have some section which you dont want to validate so what you cab do is you can use the solution given by @bansi above at the server side,  You can create an array those key which you want to validate, in `foreach` loop you can check if you `key` is available in array or not. if available then check for it's **null/blank** condition . that`s it, and if it is not available in the array then no need to validate.. so simple..  You can also use an client side validation like `jquery validations` are there if you like to use.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery validation plugin

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    <!-- write validation code -->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make it like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

    if (empty($value)) {

        //...

    } else {

        //...
    }
}
```